# converting Python function through lambda function

Tags: python, flask, lambda

Below is the custom python function that I have written.The function takes username and password to register a user through html form.

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['POST','GET'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        users = mongo.db.users 
        existing_user = users.find_one({'name':request.form['username']})

        if existing_user is None:
            hashpass = bcrypt.hashpw(request.form['pass'].encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
            users.insert({'name':request.form['username'],'password' : hashpass})
            session['username'] = request.form['username']
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

        return 'username already exist' 
    return render_template('register1.html')
```

I want to use lambda function to do the same job. as per the Lambda function syntax goes, we need to mention

```
map(lambda argument_list: expression)
```

And if I try to set the above function in this function, it would look like

```
map(lambda register:users.insert)
```

Is that the right way to fit the above "def register" function in lambda? I am very sure it would need more info in it.Please suggest.

Comment: Python is very sensible to indentation. Please, fix the indentation of your code, so we can understand it.

Comment: It wasn't me. Its Stackoverflow rule that made the code to look like that. I have edited the original code  to correct the indentation.

Comment: You are probably having [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because there is little to no reason why you should put such function inside a lambda.

Comment: why do you need a lambda function? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to reduce the number of lines to make the code lean

Comment: @user3521180 Then put everything into one line and separate statements with `;`. Wow, so lean!

Comment: yeah..Nice one, you can try that for yourself..and I guess that's what you do

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't think i understand your question. What are you trying to do with the map function? The map function receives 2 arguments... What are you trying to map?

Comment: Lets stop the discussion here, as I think my question is out of the scope .